# Expectation with $-1$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am trying to study probability theory by myself. I asked myself a question about expectation, and I have no idea how to solve it. Please help me with solution and my understanding.
The question I asked is following:
Let $a, b, c, d$ be non-negative natural numbers, say from the set $\{0, 1, ..., n\}.$
Calculate the expectation
$$
E\left( (-1)^{a+b+c+d}\right).
$$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should say something about the probability distribution of your four random variables $a,b,c,d$.

Answer (score 1):

$(-1)^{a+b+c+d} = (-1)^a (-1)^b (-1)^c (-1)^d$.  Assuming $a,b,c,d$ are independent (which you didn't say but is probably what is meant), the expected value of the product is the product of the expected values.  $(-1)^a$ is $-1$ if $a$ is odd and $1$ if $a$ is even. So if the values $0,1,\ldots,n$ are all equally likely (which again you didn't say but you probably meant), it all comes down to counting how many odd and even numbers there are in $0,1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: ...and that depends on whether $n$ is odd or even.  If $n$ is odd, then there are equally many odd and even numbers, so $E((-1)^a)$ would be $0$.  If $n$ is even, it's a bit more complicated.